# How to Set upper and lower bytes of an short int in C++

Tags: c++, typeconverter, valuestack

I got to ask How to Set upper and lower bytes of an (short int) in C++ .

we use this for get upper and lower but now how to set upper and lower bytes of a `short int`.

```
int number = 3510;

char upper = number >> 8;

char lower = number && 8;
```

thanks :)

after reading your answer i found a problem look my code please :

```
int number = 55;
int mynumber = 0;

char upper = number >> 8;

char lower = number && 8;

mynumber = (mynumber & 0xff00) | lower;
mynumber = (mynumber & 0x00ff) | (upper << 8);

printf("%i",mynumber);
```

it just return 1 but must return 55 !
how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set upper byte:

```
number = (number & 0x00ff) | (upper << 8);
```

To set lower byte:

```
number = (number & 0xff00) | lower;
```

Both upper and lower should be char or unsigned char type.